# Regex improving

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need help with improving my regex
Here you are:
https://regex101.com/r/I2c53h/3

I have the text:

```
#1234 10% activity@timing:information and other activity2@timing:adws
#3132 10% testing@1.10:test message  frontend@44min:other comments  
#3132 10% testing@1.10:test message 
#3132 10% testing@1.10
```

and use this regex:

```
(?<!\S)(\w+)@([\w.]*)\:?(\w+(?:\h\w+)*)(?!\S)
```

I need modify it. I want to use in **Group 3** not only word characters, but every possible symbols, except @, cuz it is symbol of next group.

And I want you to look at last string. Here you can see, that character **0** goes to **3rd group**. I need it to go to **2nd group**.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this question besides the fact that there is no PHP code so `regex` is the only tag needed assuming that PCRE is expected. OP has clearly tried to help themselves before posting this question, hence the link to regex101. Given that OP is likely foreign, this question has a solid amount of clarity and was brought into solid SO standards with a [nice edit by Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49070638/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your regex to this:

```
(?<!\S)(\w+)@([\w.]+)(?::([^@\n]+)(?!\S))?
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I2c53h/5)

Negated character class `[^@\n]` matches any character that is not a `@` and not `\n`

Comment: Thank you so much!